# Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation '

Tags: c#, wcf

When I try to set some values to person I get the error  in deserializing body of reply message for operation.

```
public DataRow[] person;
person = ((DataTable)wcf.getPerson(id)).Select();
```

The get person function is in the WCF services and it is `[OperationContract]`.

```
public DataTable getPerson(int id)
{
    DataTable tab = new DataTable();
    tab.TableName = "tt";
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
    {
        if(data[i].id == id)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < data[i].person.Count(); j++)
            {                        
                tab.ImportRow(data[i].person[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return tab;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide body of reply message?

Comment: what's the brackets around the `for(int j...` for ? seems like you're missing and if on your `data[i].id == id` ?

Comment: id this what you mean.   An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'getPerson'.

Comment: It gets inside the 'data[i].id == id' if statement and the brackets are there around the 'for ( int j' because it is the standard I follow.

Comment: the if is missing as I forgot to paste if (I'm an idoit) it is in origianl code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it I had to convert to a dataset and send that instead of using a dataTable Then I got the table from the set after I received it.